Label close trade's open and close points on the tradingview chart

tradingview post
I'm trying to draw shapes for the trader's open and close points. I'm attempting to use the study tool custom_indicators_getter, but it's not working as expected.
  custom_indicators_getter: function (PineJS) {
        return Promise.resolve([
          {
            name: "Label close trade",
            metainfo: {
              _metainfoVersion: 51,

              id: "LabelCloseTrade@tv-basicstudies-1",
              name: "LabelCloseTrade",
              description: "Label close trade",
              shortDescription: "Label",

              isCustomIndicator: true,
              is_price_study: true,

              format: {
                type: "price",
                precision: 4,
              },

              defaults: {
                palettes: {
                  palette_0: {
                    colors: [{ color: "#FFFF00" }, { color: "#0000FF" }],
                  },
                },
              },
              inputs: [
                {
                  id: "t_bot",
                  name: "Date and Time Bought",
                  type: "time",
                  defval: PineJS.Std.time("2024-01-01T10:00:00Z"),
                },
                {
                  id: "t_sold",
                  name: "Date and Time Sold",
                  type: "time",
                  defval: PineJS.Std.time("2024-01-01T10:00:00Z"),
                },
                {
                  id: "lot_size",
                  name: "Lot Size",
                  type: "integer",
                  defval: 1,
                  minval: 1,
                  step: 1,
                },
                {
                  id: "long_short",
                  name: "Long/Short",
                  type: "string",
                  defval: "long",
                  options: ["long", "short"],
                },
                {
                  id: "bot_val",
                  name: "Price Bought",
                  type: "float",
                  defval: 0.0,
                  minval: 0,
                },
                {
                  id: "sold_val",
                  name: "Price Sold",
                  type: "float",
                  defval: 0.0,
                  minval: 0,
                },
              ],
              plots: [
                {
                  id: "plot_0",
                  type: "shapes",
                  visible: true,
                  plottype: "shape_arrow_down",
                  location: "AboveBar",
                  color: "#920039",
                  textColor: "#879230",
                },
              ],
              palettes: {
                palette_0: {
                  colors: [{ name: "Color 0" }, { name: "Color 1" }],

                  valToIndex: {
                    100: 0,
                    200: 1,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            constructor: function () {
              this.main = function (context, input) {
                this._context = context;
                this._input = input;

                var longShort = this._input("long_short");
                var lotSize = this._input("lot_size");
                var botVal = this._input("bot_val");
                var soldVal = this._input("sold_val");
                var tBot = this._input("t_bot");
                var tSold = this._input("t_sold");

                // Using context.index to place labels
                if (longShort === "long") {
                  this._context.create_label(
                    context.index,
                    null,
                    "triangledown",
                    "#FF0000",
                    "small",
                    lotSize + " lots sold at $" + soldVal
                  );
                  this._context.create_label(
                    context.index,
                    null,
                    "triangleup",
                    "#00FF00",
                    "small",
                    lotSize + " lots bought at $" + botVal
                  );
                } else if (longShort === "short") {
                  this._context.create_label(
                    context.index,
                    null,
                    "triangledown",
                    "#00FF00",
                    "small",
                    lotSize + " lots bought at $" + botVal
                  );
                  this._context.create_label(
                    context.index,
                    null,
                    "triangleup",
                    "#FF0000",
                    "small",
                    lotSize + " lots sold at $" + soldVal
                  );
                }

                return [];
              };
            },
          },
        ]);
      },


